# Is every dynamical system approaching independence isomorphic to a Bernoulli system?

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, $f: X \rightarrow X$ be a measurable dynamical system and $\mu$ a probability on $(X, \mathcal{A})$ such that $(f,\mu)$ is an invariant system.

Suppose $\mu(A \cap f^{-n}(B)) \xrightarrow{n} \mu(A) \mu(B), \forall A,B \in \mathcal{A} $.

Is $(f,\mu)$ somehow isomorphic to a Bernoulli shift*? If not, do we have a counterexample?

Thanks in advance. Lucas A.

*PS - what I mean by a Bernoulli shift is: 
Let $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be a probability space, $(Y^\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{B}^\mathbb{N}, \nu^\mathbb{N})$ be the associated product space and $\sigma: Y^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow Y^\mathbb{N}$ be given by $(y_n)_{n \ge 0} \mapsto (y_{n+1})_{n \ge 0}$. Then $(\sigma, \nu^\mathbb{N})$ is an invariant system called a Bernoulli shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Look into Kolmogorov automorphisms. These are always mixing, but Ornstein $[1]$ provides an example of a system that is Kolmogorov, but not Bernoulli. There's undoubtedly an easier answer since not all mixing systems are Kolmogorov (K).

$[1]$ Ornestein, D. "An Example of a Kolomogorov Automorphism that is not a Bernoulli Shift." ADVANCES IN MATHEMATICS 10, 49-62 (1973)

Comment: You are right, I totally forgot that was precisely the definition of mixing. So there must be counterexamples.
If, for $A,B$ in an algebra generating $\mathcal{A}$, $\mu(A \cap f^{-n}(B)) = \mu(A)\mu(B)$ for large enough $n$, do you think the answer for the question can be positive? What if we had stronger assumptions in this direction?

In fact, I was trying to guess what an "IID dynamical system" is (this term was used in a talk and not defined). The researcher said and IID system behaves like a Bernoulli.  Do you have a guess? Eg, $\mu(A\cap f^{-n}B)=\mu(A)\mu(B)$ makes no sense.

Comment: In the first condition you talk about holds for a fixed set $A$, and all $B$ in an algebra generating the sigma algebra, for a fixed $N$ (i.e. independently of $B$, then $A$ has measure zero or one. I don't think any systems can satisfy your condition (which is slightly different than what I just mentioned, but I'm not sure of a proof off the top of my head.) I'm not sure what an IID system is for sure, perhaps a stationary process?

Comment: In the first condition 'large $n$' means larger than a $N=N(A,B)$, ie, $N$ depends on A and B. This is satisfied by a standard Bernoulli shift on a finite alphabet. Asking for a condition where $N$ does not depend on A,B or $\mu(A \cap f^{-n}B) = \mu(A)\mu(B), \forall n \ge 0$ makes no sense for the exact reason you noted (every set would need to be of measure 0 or 1). I mean, if any, only 'trivial' systems (of no interest) may have this property, so it is really not discussion worthy.

Comment: Yea, obviously the Bernoulli systems satisfy that (I need coffee!), but I did say that it was not exactly what you were asking for. As a side note, your last sentence is pretty condescending (and wholly unnecessary even if were written politely.) You'll get much better responses on here if you take the effort to be polite (even better, don't go out of your way to be not polite!)

Comment: My first guess for what an IID system was that it should have a non $\mu$-a.e. constant real-valued observable $\psi$ such that $(\psi \circ f^n)_{n \ge 0}$ was an IID family of random variables. But this property doesn't even imply ergodicity. That is why I'm still trying to discover what was the professor thinking about when referring to IID systems. I will put my head around what would mean if the system was a 'stationary process', it consequences and if it relates to Bernoulli in some straight sense.

Comment: Ops, I am really sorry. I was not my intention. I was just trying to point out that property imposed a tremendous restriction on the behavior of the system, as you also noted, making it a possibly insensible definition of what IID could be (not even Bernoullis satisfy the property). Sorry for my bad use of English :/

Comment: @LucasAmorim No worries at all! Is there any chance you could shoot them an email? I'm also interested in the question of whether your condition in the first comment implies Bernoulli. If I don't think of anything I may post it on here, if you don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72306/discussion-between-lucas-amorim-and-3-in-441).

Comment: I had an answer from the researcher. He was not willing to define what an IID system was. When saying that IID systems were like Bernoulli systems, he was only thinking that IID stochastic processes can be modeled as Bernoulli systems equipped with an appropriate observable. Modeled in the sense that both can be seen as equivalent stochastic processes (equivalent in distribution).